# Как подчеркнуть substring и добавить event в UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Есть строка "Нажмите ***сюда***, чтобы узнать больше", необходимо подчеркнуть слово "***сюда***" и добавить `event` нажатия. Как это сделать?

Comment: у UILabel есть свойство attributedText, его можно использовать вместо text и сделать там подчеркивание (в какой то момент был баг в iOS9 где это не работало, не знаю исправили ли). касательно нажатия можно положить прозрачную кнопку на то место.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko текст динамичный, и может меняться, поэтому положить кнопку сверху не подходит, так как нужное слово может находиться в разных местах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, воспользовался библиотекой https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel